# maven clean install - Failed to execute goal on project myGoogleAppEngine

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc

I've created a maven project. Before, in my pom.xml, I used the spring version 2.5.6 and now, I change the version number of spring to use the 3.1.0.RELEASE.

To update the different dependencies and update the different jar in my WEB-INF/lib, I used the following command line :'mvn clean install' and I've the following error

```
[WARNING] The POM for org.springframework:spring:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE is missing, no dependency information available
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] Total time: 0.847s
[INFO] Finished at: Sat Dec 07 13:49:20 CET 2013
[INFO] Final Memory: 4M/15M
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project myGoogleAppEngine: Could not resolve dependencies for project com.application:myGoogleAppEngine:war:0.0.1-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find org.springframework:spring:jar:3.1.0.RELEASE in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/DependencyResolutionException
```

Do you have any solutions ?

Thank you

A part of my pom.xml

```
<properties>
    <appengine.app.version>1</appengine.app.version>
    <appengine.target.version>1.8.0</appengine.target.version>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <org.springframework.version>3.1.0.RELEASE</org.springframework.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
     <!-- Spring framework -->
     <dependency>
          <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
          <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
          <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <!-- Spring MVC framework -->
     <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
           <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
     </dependency>

     <dependency>
           <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
           <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
           <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
     </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

My WEB-INF/lib

```
-spring-2.5.6.jar
-spring-aop-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-asm-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-beans-2.5.6.jar
-spring-beans-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-context-2.5.6.jar
-spring-context-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-context-support-2.5.6.jar
-spring-context-support-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-core-2.5.6.jar
-spring-core-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-expression-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-web-2.5.6.jar
-spring-web-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-spring-webmvc-2.5.6.jar
-spring-webmvc-3.1.0.RELEASE.jar
-...
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to upgrade your Spring version, upgrade it to the latest v3: `3.2.5.RELEASE` as outlined in the Maven mvn repository: http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework

However, your problem is here:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
 </dependency>
```

There is no artifactId 'spring' it should be `spring-core`.

Answer (score 0):

There is no dependancy named `org.springframework:spring:3.1.0.RELEASE`. The last jar that was available with this groupId/artifactId combination was for version `2.5.6.SEC03`.

You will have to change this dependency and re-name it to `spring-core` instead of `spring`

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
      <version>${org.springframework.version}</version>
</dependency>
```